# cross-site scripting (xss) attack

Tags: php, xss

I just have one simple question about XSS attack. I know that you can prevent them by sanitizing the form inputs, but my question is, how about a search input (a general search on a website for example)? Should we sanitize search inputs as well? I mean, it's just a search input, the user should be able to search for anything that he/she wants on the website. Please provide me with some clarification on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> > I know that you can prevent them by sanitizing the form inputs

nope, you should prevent them by sanitizing **the output**. So in database (or wherever) you need to pass the data as-is, and process it right before you show it to user

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone: it is another discussion then. Op asked specifically about XSS.

Comment: Apart from the fact that I wanna correctly display html (or other client side characters) on the website, why do I have to sanitize the OUTPUT for XSS attack (and not the INPUT)? Isn't the INPUT where the malicious code is coming from? I mean, the user enters client side code, I think that's what I should sanitize (using htmlentities()). Am I missing something else?

Comment: @user765368: yes, you're missing the fact that for different output devices you need perform different sanitize functions: to output to browser you need `htmlspecialchars`, to output to the file or email - you don't need to apply anything, etc. So before you have known *where* you output to - you cannot know how to sanitize. Also, what if you have made a mistake on input? How to "resanitize" the data? How to know what data is sanitized wrong? If you do it on output - then you just fix it once in one place and don't have such headache.

Answer (score 3):

Tho this has already been answered by zerkms

Doing sanitizing on sql injections from any user input that touches the database requires `mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['search'])`

On output if your showing what user searched for like "You searched for:" use `htmlentities(strip_tags($_REQUEST['search']), ENT_QUOTES);`

Then your safe from incoming and outgoing

Comment: Apart from correctly showing what the user have searched for, to protect a website from xss attack, isn't the INPUT what needs to be sanitize? Are there other purposes to sanitizing the output?

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add one more point to the discussion here.  You said:

> I mean, it's just a search input, the user should be able to search for anything that he/she wants on the website.

Here's the gotcha: frequently the search term will be printed into the document that's rendered following the search.  Ie, "You searched for: <whatever is was>".  That's where you'll have your XSS vulnerability if you're not sanitizing this stuff.

If you're thinking "but we don't do that", bear in mind that you may not do so *now*, but you might do so *in the future*.  And if you don't seal off this vulnerability now, you're likely to forget to do so later - so it's best just to nip this one in the bud.

Answer (score 1):

how about using [htmlpurifier ?](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Answer (score 1):

**SQL Injection** and **XSS** are two different (yet somewhat related) attacks. They are related in that essentially it boils down to the untrusted data escaping from the context it was placed in and subsequently performing unforeseen operations.

For following best practices in building your defenses I recommend having a read through **OWASP's** [SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) and their [XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

OWASP has put forth the [ESAPI Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI#tab=Home) which includes tools for encoding for the different contexts in which untrusted data can be used:

- encodeForSQL
- encodeForHTML
- encodeForHTMLAttribute
- encodeForJavaScript
- encodeForCSS
- encodeForURL

This library is available for a number of languages including Java, .NET, **PHP**, Classic ASP, Cold Fusion, Python, and Haskell. It also is able to perform input validation if it's required.

Some organisations who are using ESAPI include American Express, Apache Foundation, Booz Allen Hamilton, Aspect Security, Foundstone(McAfee), The Hartford, Infinite Campus, Lockheed Martin, MITRE, U.S. Navy - SPAWAR, The World Bank, SANS Institute.

Lastly - the encoding is to be performed just before interpretation (the closer the better). Ex: Just before you give the UI component the untrusted data to render you encode it. The UI component can't trust the server - it has to encode.